# Gas oven goes "Thup" every 5 to 30 minutes. What to do?

Tags: oven, natural-gas

An 8 year old natural gas oven has been making a sound occasionally.  It seems to be every 5 minutes or so when the oven starts and then less frequently.  The sound is not very loud, but loud enough to be clearly heard from across the room.  This has been going on for at least a couple of years (but I just found out about it).  What should I do about this noise?

Update: The first 3 comments give a wide range of opinions, from highly dangerous to that is how the oven works.  I would like to hear from some other people familiar with gas ovens, including owners of such
ovens.

Update 2: One oven manufacturer's website says, "It is possible to hear a whooshing or popping sound from any type of gas burners when the burner ignites on start-up and reignites during use." https://www.subzero-wolf.com/assistance/answers/gas-burner-noise-during-use

This surely is confusing to a non-expert.

Update 3 years later: The noise has not re-occurred.  The new igniter solved the problem.

Comment: Sounds like your oven burner ignition is malfunctioning, allowing gas to build up and then igniting (  THUP ---  small explosion ).   **Stop using it** before it creates a big explosion. You need a technician or replace the unit.

Comment: I'll just add IMMEDIATELY! He's right, that's the sound of your gas igniting in an unexpected manner, probably due to a leak somewhere. It is already dangerous and will continue to get more so.

Comment: My Frigidaire oven has been doing the same thing for its 10 year life. Apparently , it happens each time it relights to maintain temperature. I don't like it so I turn the TV louder.

Comment: @J.Raefield  Hmm. That is a wide range of opinions. I would like to hear from more owners of Frigidare ovens.

Comment: This is not normal and you should not get a consensus. Call someone to repair it or if it is very old, replace it. Try not to use it until then

Comment: it sounds like thermal expansion causing a metal panel to shift under tension. This happens to us all with baking pans, but it can happen to the metal sheets in the oven as well, especially the floor. Can you watch it warm up and see if you can see the moving part? Not exciting i know, but will provide some re-assurance if it's only a cosmetic shift and not your gas main about to blow...

Comment: Even though you're getting a range of possible issues, I'd definitely parrot @UnhandledExcepSean and say *do not wait for a consensus*! The first 2 comments point to this being incredibly dangerous. Get a professional rather than relying on speculative votes even though it *could* be normal. I would consider the cost of a professional to far offset the risk of your oven/home exploding...

Comment: Glad your issue is fixed, just curious, how much did this service call cost? As my oven started taking longer to ignite and finally stopped altogether and I just replaced my hot surface igniter for $35 + shipping and was wondering how much money I saved.

Comment: @GlenYates Service call fee was $213 (in 2019).

Answer (score 4):

RESOLUTION: WEAK IGNITER, NO DANGER.

I called in an appliance repair person.  The "Thup" sound was just the gas coming on. (I watched the gas igniting and heard the thup at the same time, several times.)  The repair person said the igniter was weak.  It took over 60 seconds for the igniter to ignite the gas when the oven was first turned on. The weak igniter was hot enough to light the gas, but the weakness caused the gas to go off.  When the gas went off, it stayed off for a short time (perhaps 15 sec), after which the gas came on again and ignited. This on-off-on  happened every 30 sec or so when the oven was first turned on.  After the oven was hot, the on-off happened very infrequently.  Probably the oven was operating properly after it was hot, going off when the target temperature was reached and going on when the temp dropped below that target.  The appliance repair person said there was no safety issue but sooner or later the weak igniter would not ignite the gas.  In any case, a new igniter solved the problem.  With the new igniter, the gas lit 30 sec after the oven was turned on and the on-off-on cycling was gone: the gas just stayed lit.

I do not know why a weak igniter would cause the gas to go off after was lit.  I would think that a heat sensor would detect the flame.  The repair person said there was no separate heat sensor.  So, it seems the igniter serves as the heat sensor also.

Comment: "Flame proving" can be accomplished with the igniter itself. With a spark type igniter electrical characteristics of the spark change when the spark goes through flame and the control circuit can detect this. With a hot surface type igniter the electrical characteristics of the igniter itself change when it is heated by the flame and this too can be detected. I wonder if a "weak igniter" led to the flame extinguishing itself -- the sudden puff of the gas burning might actually extinguish the burn if conditions are right, and the weak igniter may be unable to re-ignite the gas.

Comment: @GregHill. TY for the explanation of the sensor.  There was no spark and the igniter glowed red/white, so the ignite was the hot surface type.  The puff was just heard and seen when the gas was off.  It was the noise of the gas coming on.  The puff and the newly ignited gas was heard and seen simultaneously.